# Xserve 1,1 and PCIe 1x Nvidia compatibility

Tags: kernel-extensions, video-adapter, xserve

I have a GeForce GT 610 that I have been trying to figure out how to get the Xserve to utilize. I have followed various guides and ideas to no luck. The screen on this card is always black and the system does see something on the PCIe bus but just doesn't send video.

I have tried various hackintosh kext files but I am at a loss.
Is there more options that I just have not found?

I have it running Snow Leopard desktop with the .8 update

Comment: Have you installed the Nvidia graphics driver? It may need it to work properly.

Comment: I tried that yes. Also tried manually loading different video kext files.

Comment: Hmmm... I know someone who was also having trouble with a 645... I don't know if they ever figured it out...